# Does $\sum_{k=1}^\infty(1+\frac{1}{2}+ \dots +\frac{1}{k})\frac{\sin kx}{k}$ converge absolutely?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

For $x\neq k\pi,k\in\mathbb{Z}$,does the following series converge absolutely?

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty(1+\frac{1}{2}+ \dots +\frac{1}{k})\frac{\sin kx}{k}$$

Comment: Changed your sum from $n$ to $k$. Let me know if you meant for the index to be $k$ and the summand to be with $n$, though it wouldn't make much sense. Also, it's usually nice to give your thoughts on the problem so others are more willing to help out.

Answer (score 1):

**Helpful Observation:** note that
$$
1 + \frac 12 + \cdots + \frac 1k=\ln(k)+\gamma + o(1)
$$
Where $\gamma$ is a constant (the Euler-Mascheroni constant, in fact) and $o(1)$ is some sequence converging to zero.

---

The answer to your question is that the sequence converges conditionally, but not absolutely. It is possible to show conditional convergence using the Dirichlet test and show absolute divergence with a comparison test.

Answer (score 0):

Does it converge absolutely even without the $\left(1+\cdots+\frac{1}{k}\right)$? I doubt it. For most fixed $x$, a *nearly* arithmetic progression of $k$-values will leave $\left|\sin kx\right|$ very close to $1$, and so a subseries would involve a series with similar features to the Harmonic series. Tossing in the $\left(1+\cdots+\frac{1}{k}\right)$ just makes it less able to converge.

(Whether it converges *conditionally* is a different question.)

Comment: @alexWhat is a "nearly arithmetic progression"?

Comment: @CWeid For the sake of brevity, I'd rather not make it formal. But for the right values of integers $a$ and $b$, then for $k$ up to a point, $(a\,k+b)x$ will be close to $\frac{\pi}{2}+m\pi$. After a point, this won't hold any more and $a$ will need to be adjusted. But I doubt this will have any impact on the summability of the series; it will still be a positive series that includes a subseries that is so close to a scaled Harmonic series that it can't converge.